# Testing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I heard there have some built in option for testing(Nunit etc..) in visual studio.let me know the best method for testing MVC4  web application using with this methods.and  i am using VS2013 profession edition.

Answer (score 1):

There is MSTest which is available in visual studio. 
[Get started with developer testing tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/developer-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-developer-testing)